# Change a master pages footer source programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP webform which consists of a MasterPage with a header and footer control and my content placeholder.

I have a link within the header which triggers a change of language culture by altering the query string of the Uri.

This all works perfectly well, however my footer contains a few fields which are currently separate to all this.

What I would like to do is on the `Page_Load` for `MasterPage` if the current threads culture is Welsh, point at the Welsh version of my footer, however I do not know how to get a handle on the footer's source.

```
    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "cy-GB")
    {
        string debug = Footer1.ToString();                
    }
```

When I change the language and inspect the debug string I can see the value is: `ASP.components_footer2_ascx` my idea is to change this to `ASP.components_footer2_cy_gb_ascx`
How can I redirect the source of the footer within this if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you add both ascx objects to your masterpage then on page_load check for Welsh culture and make visible or invisible the relevant ascx object?